# Progressive fixed Coupon Discount based on specific product quantity in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, product-quantity

I have one little problem that dont know how to fix myself. I want to use this logic into my Woocommerce store just for one product.

I have use link like this to autmatically apply coupon code and add to cart:

```
https://testsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=Product_ID&quantity=1&coupon=Coupon_Code
```

and this seems to work, when quantity is 1. But i want discount (30%) that is automatically placed  when click on direct link from before, to make dynamic, for ex:

- Increase quantity to 2 in cart page, and coupon automatically to calculate `2 x 30$ = 60$` discount,
- buy 3 from same product, and calculate `3 X 30$ = 90$` coupon discount
  and so on..

I searched, and found this [usefull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570692/woocommerce-add-a-discount-based-on-individual-items-quantity) thread, but there situation is little different then mine.

How can I make to have a specific coupon? Some advice or start point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with that 2 steps:

1) Add a unique coupon with:

- In General settings > Type = **Fixed Product discount**
- In General settings > Amount = `30`
- In Usage restrictions > Products ==> **set your desired product**(s)

2) Add this code (where you will set your coupon code in the function (in lowercase)):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'custom_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
function custom_coupon_get_discount_amount( $rounded_discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){

    ## ---- Your settings ---- ##

    // Related coupons codes to be defined in this array (you can set many)
    $coupon_codes = array('30perqty');

    ## ------ The code ------- ##

    if ( $coupon->is_type('fixed_product') && in_array( $coupon->get_code(), $coupon_codes ) && $cart_item['quantity'] > 1 ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $coupon->get_product_ids() ) ){
            $discount = (float) $coupon->get_amount() * (int) $cart_item['quantity'];
            $round = round( min( $discount, $discounting_amount ), wc_get_rounding_precision() );
        }
    }
    return $rounded_discount;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: This code works perfectly, but when use direct link for ex:
`https://siteurl.com/checkout1/?add-to-cart=319&coupon=gss30`

coupon is not showed in checkout page. Why ? See image.

https://i.imgur.com/2q3HanP.png?1

Comment: @DavidCopper … In your question you asked just for my actual code… But you didn't ask for something that will add a coupon in cart from your custom add-to-cart URL and so you may ask a new related question.